# Loop in Spark. Simulation

Tags: java, loops, apache-spark, tree, simulation

Is it possible to solve simulation issues using spark?
For Example:
I need to simulate some organism birth-and-death process. Stop condition: (population = 0 || population > X) where X is 1,000,000,000 for example.

Is it possible to use loop with some kind of condition? If "YES" what is the best way to implement this loop. If "NO" is there any other mechanism to provide stop conditions?

Now I see several options how to solve this issue:

To control stop condition I can use:

1. Accumulator // is it safe?
2. call organismRdd.size // what about performance?

To simulate process I can use:

1. flatMap with organism.nextEpoch() call which returns organisms iterator
2. I can use forEach but in this case I need to implement some logic in Organism to keep all "child" nodes in some king of tree

JAVA Pseudocode example:

```
Accumulator population = new Accumulator();
JavaRDD<Organism> organismRdd = ...// create RDD
while(population = 0 || population > X)
{
    organismRdd = organismRdd.flatMap(organism -> organism.nextEpoch()) // return next epoch organisms iterator
    // update population accumulator
}
```

Comment: It is definitely possible, but I don't think Spark would be the best tool to do that.

Comment: This is only example. Real issue is much more complex. And one VM is not enough to solve this issue in acceptable time. That is why I want to use Spark. I want try spark cluster to solve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the stop condition, you can use `rdd.count()`.
This will actually be necessary, since just calling `flatMap` doesn't execute anything because Spark rdd transformations are lazily evaluated.
You also want to `.cache()` your rdd after every step to avoid recomputation.

To generate new organisms, `flatMap` is a good option.
You could also use `mapPartitions` depending on your requirements.